# IIS rewriting location header before ARR

Tags: iis, http, arr

We have a rewrite configuration that treats ARR as a reverse proxy in a configuration like this:

```
Browser client (OriginA) <-> IIS/ARR (OriginB) <-> Server
```

The client is any number of web browsers. We cannot change this configuration.

1. The client requests http://originb/return with a URL such as http://origina/done.html in the request.
2. ARR then forwards the request to http://server/return.
3. The server responds with the `Location` header set to http://origina/done.html and HTTP 302. I've verified this with Wireshark.
4. IIS somewhere in the pipeline is changing the `Location` header to http://originb/done.html. **This is where the problems begin.**
5. ARR sees the originb URL in a PATTERN_MATCH step for the `Location` header.
6. ARR reports the originb URL as the `Location` header in the GENERAL_RESPONSE_HEADERS step.
7. The client blindly accepts the URL and redirects to the non-existent http://originb/done.html instead of http://origina/done.html

I've cranked up Failed Request Tracing and thats how I saw steps 5 and 6.

What could be causing IIS to rewrite the `Location` header before ARR? Are there any other IIS tools I can use to figure this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My Googlefu was failing me today.

In the `Server Proxy Settings` pane of IIS Manager, I needed to uncheck "Reverse rewrite host in response headers".

Comment: Thanks, I was searching for this all over website settings, but it turns out it is global setting

Answer (score 1):

In IIS 7, click the **server** that runs the AAR/does the rewriting (**above** sites, application pools, etc) - then open "Application Request Routing Cache". In the "Actions" menu on the right hand "Actions" pane, under "Proxy", click "Server Proxy Settings". In the resulting dialogue, ensure "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" is **unchecked** (see image).

[dialogue with tickbox image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAr45.png)